# Dreamweaver source code view, is it possible to add "tags"?

Tags: dreamweaver

I do'nt know if this is possible or if its called tags

im using dreamweaver cs4, in source mode view it displays line numbers to the left, I wish I could add some kind of "tag" to a certain line, and then have some sort of menu where it scrolls me to the tag.

Does this makes any sense?

It's because I have a huge source file that I need to navigate a lot in different places while coding and this "feature" would make my life a LOT easier.

Any help is appreciated.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking is what I've heard called a number of times "bookmarking". Unfortunately, Dreamweaver does not have this functionality built in. Not quite the same thing, but if you remember the line number you can jump to the line using a keyboard shortcut: CTRL+G on Windows, I think Cmd+, on Mac this pop up a little dialog you can enter the line number and hit enter to jump to that line.

Comment: exactly I wanted bookmarks, is there a nice editor with them that also code higlights like dreamweaver?

Comment: Eclipse has link bookmarking, but I haven't used it in quite a while, so not sure about how easy it is to use. I'm sure other editors have that as well. Eclipse has a variety of plugins that can give you code coloring for a lot of languages, but I haven't seen a design surface similar to Dreamweaver's Design view if you need that too.